# Watson Assistant Chatbot integration on Wix website

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, velo, watson-assistant

I have integrated a Watson Assistant Chatbot into a Wix website using "add > embed > htmliframe"

PROBLEM: when I scroll down the page, the chatbot icon dissapears.

What can I do in order for the chatbot icon to continue being visible when the page is scrolled down?

Would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only UI elements that can be frozen on the screen with the Wix editor are the header and footer.

You can recreate this experience by using either anchor points or other hidden UI elements to show/hide different iFrame elements within the page. By using the viewport enter and leave events, you can show/hide these elements but it won't create the exact seamless experience of a frozen element.

If you can, you can attach it to your footer and then freeze your footer so it will always be sticky at the bottom of your screen.

Comment: thanks a lot for your kind help. I attached it to the footer, froze the latter, and it works just fine. You rock it!!! –